# android - Handle exception to update UI

Tags: java, android, exception, kotlin, try-catch

In my application I'd like to:

- Have a method A inside a Fragment
- From within method A, call a method B that is annotated with `@Throws(IOException::class)`
- From within method B, call a method C that has a `try catch` and at the `catch` it `throw IOException(e)`

  Receive error inside method A and do stuff with info

So far I have:

```
fun methodA() {
    methodB()
    //Get exception and do stuff
}

@Throws(IOException::class)  
fun methodB() {
    methodC()
}  

fun methodC() {
    try {
        //Something that can throw exception
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw IOException(e)
    }
}
```

Is that the right way or a excepted way? But still, how do I get that a exception was thrown inside method A? I was thinking of something like:

```
fun methodA() {
    try {
        methodB()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        //received exception thrown by method C and do stuff
    }
}
```

Will I be able to achieve what I want with that? If not, can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: There is no need to use try-catch in methodC to throw exception, if you want to your function to throw an Exception annotate it first then throw your Exception inside it, if another function calls that function it has to either handle that exception or throw it, for your case since the Exception is generated in `methodC()` and propagated up to `methodA` then both `methodC()` and `methodB()` have to be annotated  to throw your desired Exception, throw your exception in `methodC()` it will propagate through `methodB()` thereafter use try-catch in `methodA()` to handle the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work (if you use your second version of `methodA()`). But why are you catching the exception in `methodC()`, only to throw a new copy of it? Instead, consider the following:

```
fun methodA() {
    try {
        methodB()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // error flow
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun methodB() {
    methodC()
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun methodC() {
    // do something that can throw exception
}
```

The `IOException` propagates upward to `methodA()`, where you can handle it.

You could also consider catching the exception deeper in the call stack:

```
fun methodA() {
    val err = methodB()
    if (err) {
        // error flow
    } else {
        // normal flow
    }
}

fun methodB(): Boolean {
    return methodC()
}

fun methodC(): Boolean {
    return try {
        // do something that can throw exception
        false
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        true
    }
}
```

Now, which of these two approaches should you use? It depends on your actual code. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972307/when-to-return-bool-throw-an-exception-and-which-exception-to-throw) is a discussion.

(One other problem with the code that you gave is that `methodB()` is superfluous. But I'll assume that it does something interesting in your actual program.)